# Centring two images within a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following div

```
<div id = "photos">
    <%= image_tag("profile.jpg", :id => "profile", :class => "img-thumbnail")%>
    <%= image_tag("coverEagle.jpg", :id => "banner") %>

</div>
```

Here is the relevant css

```
#photos{
    align-items: middle;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#banner{
    max-height:270px;
    width:900px;
    max-width:100%;
}
#profile{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am trying to centre the profile image inside the photos div however it seems that the code above does not work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to center the `#profile` image but there is no code trying to center it.

it's a position absolute image, so something like this should work.

```
#profile {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

other way is to add:

```
#photos{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

It'll center all the items inside it.